# is a uA current FET or BJT circuit design possible?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, bjt, low-power, fet

I'm working on a battery powered circuit that is triggering an interrupt on an ic with an internal pull-up. The resistor value and normally closed switch can not be changed. The quiescent current is way too high for our application 200uA. Our target is 0-6uA.

Is there a FET/BJT circuit that could be added between the switch and the ic that could be designed to achieve the target current?

Any ideas? 
Thanks

[image: circuit]

**EDIT comment

**I was using the NC switch to represent a physical characteristic of our device, now that I think about it it's more like a fuse. ie. We are trying to detect when the fuse is blown.

Comment: Why not use an external pull-up, instead of the internal pull-up of the micro?? A lot of micro allow you to turn off the ICs internal pull ups, and you can do something like an 0402 resistor so it wont take much space??

Comment: Or disable the pullup and use a SPDT switch instead.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can deal with an inverted signal you could use the following (If the ideas in the comments don't work.)  The 2N7002 Vth might be a bit high, so you should look for a tiny low threshold FET.

If you need the signal to be the same polarity you can add another transistor inverter stage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkC4PW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

John has shown you a way to do this. Of course if you really need that pin to be low and really can't turn off the 11k then you will have hundreds of uA.

Another method that might be useful if you can use polling rather than an interrupt is to briefly test the switch at intervals using a resistor and a port pin. A healthy 1mA pulse for 100usec at 10Hz is only 1uA average. This has the advantage that minor leakage will not cause problems and perhaps dealing with the fact that some mechanical switches are not very reliable at extremely low currents and have a minimum current rating.

Comment: Interesting..

I just read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67280/difference-between-reading-port-and-pin

It looked like the consensus on that page was that using the port pin would only allow reading the configuration of the pull-up resistor?

Comment: Drive the current through a pullup with the port pin, and read on another port pin. Two pins, one signal. If you want to get tricky, there are ways to do it with one pin.